# Get name of Amazon Web Services Codecommit Repository in triggered Lambda function

Tags: python, git, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-codecommit

I've created a trigger in my AWS CodeCommit repositories which runs a Lambda function whenever it is triggered. The Lambda function calls a script at my development server to perform a git pull. So far so good.

The problem is that I need to pass the name or ID of the repository that sets off the trigger to the dev machine so I can git pull the correct repository. My question then, **is how do you call the name or id of the repository which triggered the Lambda function within the Lambda function?**

My Lambda function is written in **Python**.

I've taken a look at the Lambda documentation at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html but there is no mention of CodeCommit. This is probably because CodeCommit triggers are quite new - only a few months old. There is some documentation of event sources at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html . I followed the tutorial at - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-notify-lambda.html to create the Lambda function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to pull out the repository is in the Python [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-notify-lambda.html). The code snippet is:

```
#Get the repository from the event and show its git clone URL
repository = event['Records'][0]['eventSourceARN'].split(':')[5]
```

The repository name is embedded in the ARN that the Lambda function receives.

Comment: Thank you. When I previously followed that tutorial the example function was very different. Seems they've updated it into something a little more useful

Comment: does anyone know where documentation for the event object can be found? What exactly is contained in event.Records? I'd like to extract the branch name from the event but have no idea what the event contains